# Stripe Onboarding return and redirect url

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

Can someone help me by explaining how to use the redirect and return URL in the Stripe onboarding? I know what they are for, but I do not understand how to implement them. Below is all I can find. I am new to this part of android. I am also writing in java.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the redirect and return URLs for onboarding new Stripe connect accounts? You'll likely want to look at the documentation on how to onboard new accounts, specifically this section (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#return-user) which talks about what you should implement for each URL. If you have more questions you may want to talk to Stripe's support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact)

Comment: Yes and I have read that documentation already. What I am struggling to understand, is how to tell create these URLs. For example, I have read that the return URL should be in the Android manifest but I do not know how to code that part. I am basically asking for a beginners course in programming these correctly.

Comment: im facing a similar issue , have you found any information? I am supplying the return url, but it does not redirect back to mobile app